# Proof of a graph problem on degree sequence

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that:
order of natural number $d_1 , d_2 , \ldots , d_n$ as descending is a ordering graph if and only if the order was sorted as descending $d_2-1, d_3 -1 , \ldots ,d_d -1,\ldots ,d_n$ be ordering graph.
$d_d$ in sequence is d  $d_1$.
(arrangement=order).

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you are trying to state the [result of Hakimi for vertex degree sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you know that $d=d_1\ge d_2 \ge \dots \ge d_n$ are degrees of vertices of some graph, what can you say about degrees of the graph where the vertex of degree $d_1$ is omitted? Can you go in opposite direction, too? (I.e. can you obtain from a graph with degrees $d_1-1,\dots,d_d-1,d_{d+1},\dots,d_n$ a graph with degrees $d_1,d_2,\dots,d_n$?)

(I assume that the interpretation of your question given in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218156/proof-of-a-graph-problem-on-degree-sequence#comment490863_218156) is correct and that the question is about [Havel-Hakimi theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V._J._Havel#Havel.E2.80.93Hakimi_theorem).)